# Getting started with Blend for Visual Studio 2012 Documentation .pdf

Tags: visual-studio-2012, documentation, blend

Hi there: How can I download "Getting started with Blend for Visual Studio 2012" documentation from Microsoft website in .pdf format? I dont want to use the internet the whole time when I want this documentation...
Here is the link of the documntation  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download it and go to the download folder, Use a PDF reader to view the document. Acrobat PDF reader is free. 
https://get.adobe.com/reader/

Comment: can you gimme some more explanation please

Comment: If you can download the PDF file from microsoft then go to where the file downloaded to and double click the file it should open, if it does not please use the link to download the reader and install. once installed you will be able to open the file.